# NavigationBar shadowImage not showing with large title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, preferslargetitles

I added a custom divider in my app via `navigationBar.shadowImage` and it works just fine with a small title. But when I scroll so that the NavigationBar shows the large title, the shadowImage disappears.

So far I haven't found post addressing this problem, only posts concerning the background of the navigationBar as a whole. How could I go about adding a shadowImage to the navigationBar in "large title mode" or will i have to add the divider in the layout manually?

Comment: add your code here.

Comment: What code do you expect? I've set large title, i've set a shadowimage. its two lines of code.